# Alternatives to RDP under Windows 7 Professional using 2 monitors

Tags: windows, rdp

My PC at work has Windows 7 Professional Edition which I know I cannot use the regular RDP to connect using 2 monitors.

Is there any alternative I can use to connect to a Windows 7 Professional Edition via RDP?

Comment: What's this about two monitors?  What doesn't work?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional Edition doesn't support RDP with multiple monitors. I was wondering If I can make it work using an alternative. [See this link for more info](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Remote-Desktop-Connection-frequently-asked-questions)

Comment: Off topic. Belongs on SuperUser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to clear this up

Windows 7 pro can use true multiple monitors when it is the client (connecting to server 2008/windows 7 ult or enterprise)

When it is the HOST (ie the one you are connecting to) it will only allow single monitor connections to it, the span option works to stretch the session over 2 screens but it ISNT true multimonitor mode

Sorry sam but you cant connect to windows 7 pro in tru multimon mode, the screenshot you have shown is the remote desktop client, hence why the options are there

Comment: Actually, it can work if you install RDPWrap - https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap - it doesn't say, but it enables multimon rdp support in win 7 pro as well. Yay! :)

Answer (score -1):

The situation is that when Win7 Pro is the *host* (meaning it is the remote machine), it does NOT provide multiple monitor support.

No matter what settings you use on the client, you will get only a single monitor, if the host is Win7 Pro. Period.

The sad fact is that the Win7 FAQ - for a long time - said ALL versions of Win7 supported multiple monitors through RDP, without qualification.

After many users complained of this failing with Win7 Pro as the host, Microsoft fixed it - by changing the FAQ. Frankly, Microsoft owes this feature to all Win7 users, but Win8 is now the new (and obviously, at the time of this writing, failed) focus of attention.

There ARE programs out there that patch Windows Home to have full RDP hosting (actually, the 2008 server version, which allows multiple remote desktops). Apparently it is a single DLL and, possibly, some registry changes. I have no idea if they'd work for Pro, but my guess is that they would.

That said, if you have an IT department managing your host PC, you probably can't do this, and will have spend $130 to use the Anytime upgrade to the Ultimate version.

This despite the fact that the overwhelming desktop being remotely connected to at businesses is Pro. Yeah, I think MS just found a possible cash cow, and of course won't ever admit it, or live up the promise they made via their FAQ for quite a long time.

Answer (score -2):

Win7 does have duel monitor support
WinXP does not
As long as the PC you are using, and the PC you are connected to is Win7, there should not be a problem. Also the PC you are Using the RDP connection from must have duel screens. If not you well have to use a VNC like Teamviewer.
See below
[image]

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm using Windows 7 Professional Edition. Only Enterprise or Ultimate have support for dual monitors.

Comment: Professional does support that ability. We are using Win 7 Professional and We have that ablity. Are you sure your not using Home Edition.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Are you able to connect to Natalie-PC (the PC with Windows Professional) from another computer using 2 monitors using RDP?

Comment: this is really weird. it can't. it's posted every where it can't. And i am unable to that that on my win7 professional. 
aside all that. i wouldn't wanna be the guy using  rpd to a machine with only 2gb of mem.